Using the dominated convergence theorem to evaluate the integral of independent events
I've spent the last 3 days trying to solve this problem but i couldn't get anywhere. The problem is the following:
Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a probability space (ie, $\mu(X) = 1$).
Prove that if $E_n \in \mathcal{A}$, $n = 1,2,...$, are independent then:
$\int_X \prod_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-\chi_{E_n}(x)}d\mu = \prod_{n=1}^\infty[1 - \frac{1}{2}\mu(E_n)]$
I know that i can write $\prod_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-\chi_{E_n}(x)} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty[ 1 - \frac{1}{2}\chi_{E_n^c}(x)]$
I also tried partioning $X$ into other sets. I'm supposed to use the dominated convergence theorem, but i'm not sure how. Should i evaluate the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{j=1}^n[ 1 - \frac{1}{2}\chi_{E_j^c}(x)]$? If so, how do i do it?
Can someone give me a hint?

Let $X_k=\prod_{n=1}^k 2^{-\chi_{E_n}}$. Then $0 \le X_k \le 1$ and $X_k \to X$ where $X=\prod_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-\chi_{E_n}}$. Hence $\int Xd\mu=\lim \int X_k d\mu$ (by DCT). By indepndence we get $\int X_k d\mu= \prod_{n=1}^k \int 2^{-\chi_{E_n}}d\mu$. It remains only to note that $\int 2^{-\chi_{E_n}}d\mu=2^{-1} \mu (E_n)+2^{-0}\mu(E_n^{c})=2^{-1} \mu (E_n)+(1-\mu(E_n))=1-\frac1  2\mu (E_n)$.
